# Chronicle: How to optimize memory-mapped files for low-latency?

Tags: real-time, low-latency, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I'm using Chronicle to transfer vast amounts of data from one JVM to another. Problem is that I notice a lot of jitter on my benchmarks. My knowledge of memory-mapped files is somewhat limited, but I do know that the OS swaps pages back and forth from memory to disk.

How do I configure those pages for maximum performance, in my case, for less jitter and the lowest possible latency, when using Chronicle? Do they need to be big or small? Do they need to be many or few?

Here is what I currently have on my Ubuntu box:

```
$ cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
AnonHugePages:      2048 kB
ShmemHugePages:        0 kB
HugePages_Total:       1
HugePages_Free:        1
HugePages_Rsvd:        0
HugePages_Surp:        0
Hugepagesize:    1048576 kB
```

Comment: Don't use memory-mapped files if you need a guaranteed latency. (mapped shared memory objects are fine though) There is no way to optimise. Use file access with O_SYNC and O_DIRECT, lock the process in memory, disable swap, and do all the other stuff mandatory for a real-time latency. Stock JVM is also not an option, there are some real-time ready JVM versions though.

Comment: `mapped shared memory objects are fine though` => how does that work? I thought for obvious security reasons you would never be allowed to access other process memory, unless you use a memory-mapped file as a bridge. You can't simply access any block of memory from your application, without first allocating it for itself.

Comment: A shared memory region in Unix is a special block device "file" that you can `mmap()`.

Comment: But then how another process will gain access to this same region of memory? It sounds forbidden, no?

Comment: By using its name, in "/dev/shm/WhateverYouNameYourRegion"

Comment: So there is no page swapping inside `/dev/shm/`? Everything just goes to memory? So provided you have enough RAM memory it is a much faster solution than memory-mapped files, correct?

Comment: Yes, correct - mmap is only ok for shared memory regions, provided you mlock-ed them all and don't have swap. Mmap cannot be used for real file i/o, anything that'd access slow data storage. If everything configured correctly you should see a zero latency communication.

Comment: @SK-logic you can get the 99.99% latency well below 10 microseconds with stock JVMs.

Comment: `/dev/shm` is still a memory-mapped file, just not backed by disk.

Comment: @PeterLawrey, not if you do any file i/o. Not if there's any context switching involved (and with stock jvm it's hardly possible to avoid). You will have an average latency below 10us, but there will be few ms spikes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059608/best-practices-for-java-ipc-through-dev-shm-with-the-lowest-possible-latency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have Linux, you can enable sparse files with `useSparseFiles(true)` on the builder.

You can also use a faster drive to reduce outliers or `/dev/shm`.

There is an asynchronous mode in the closed source version, however, you can get most outliers well below 80 microseconds without it.

Chronicle Queue doesn't use Huge pages.

Here is a chart I created when I was comparing it to Kafka, writing to a Corsair MP600 Pro XT.

http://blog.vanillajava.blog/2022/01/benchmarking-kafka-vs-chronicle-for.html

NOTE: This is the latency for two hops writing and reading an object of around 220 bytes (with serialization)

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Peter. Where can I read more about `sparse files`? Is it something offered by the operating system to increase performance?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71059608/best-practices-for-java-ipc-through-dev-shm-with-the-lowest-possible-latency

Comment: Are those numbers shown in the graph average latencies?

Comment: @rogerkasinsky Unix supports sparse files which results in only the page actually written to being allocated on disk or memory. The average latency is between the typical (50%) and 90% latencies. Average latencies are a great way to hide occasional poor performance so a latency distribution is better.