# What is the correct way of doing Java IPC through /dev/shm (with the lowest possible latency)

Tags: java, real-time, low-latency, chronicle, chronicle-queue

I'm trying to code an IPC solution through `/dev/shm`.

@SK-logic gave me some pointers in the comments here: [Chronicle: How to optimize memory-mapped files for low-latency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71026357/chronicle-how-to-optimize-memory-mapped-files-for-low-latency)

**My doubt is:** Should I use a `MappedByteBuffer` or just a plain `FileChannel`?

With a `MappedByteBuffer` I can use `sun.misc.Unsafe` and have direct access to memory. That's fantastic because `Unsafe` gives me methods like `getLongVolatile` (in addition to `getLong`) and `putLongVolatile` (in addition to `putLong`). Is that even possible if I use a plain `FileChannel`? How would I avoid reading cached data from the CPU cache with a plain `FileChannel` reading from `/dev/shm/`? Do I have to configure something in the operating system for volatile reads and writes from `/dev/shm`? What? Where? How? :)

**What is the correct way of doing Java IPC through `/dev/shm`? Plain FileChannel? MappedByteBuffer?**

Below how I get the pointer to memory through `sun.misc.Unsafe`:

```
    try {
        this.raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");
        this.fileChannel = raf.getChannel();
        this.mappedBuffer = this.fileChannel.map(MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, size);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not mmap file to memory: " + filename + " " + size, e);
    }
    
    try {
        addressField = Buffer.class.getDeclaredField("address");
        addressField.setAccessible(true);
        this.pointer = (long) addressField.get(this.mappedBuffer);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not get off-heap pointer!", e);
    }
```

Comment: Please read: ["No Best Practices"](https://www.satisfice.com/blog/archives/5164)

Comment: You cannot read cpu cache. Try benchmark both solutions and tell us which one was better.

Comment: What do you mean by _You cannot read cpu cache_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chronicle Queue uses `Unsafe` for thread-safe memory access for heap and direct memory.

While this works, the JVM doesn't provide any guarantees as to how your system will behave. We test on Intel X64, AMD, and ARM processors.

Rather than writing this all yourself, why not try Chronicle Map or Queue to do this for you?

Comment: I'm using Chronicle already, but I'm curious to know how it is done. Do you use a `FileChannel` or a `MappedByteBuffer` with `Unsafe`? According to what I've heard from @SK-logic, `MappedByteBuffer` has overhead, even inside `/dev/shm`.

Comment: Also, when you said `heap memory` above, you probably meant `direct memory`.

Comment: @RogerKasinsky MappedByteBuffer has a small overhead but lacks thread safe operations or 64 bit offsets. Bytes supports 63 bit offsets, thread safe and low/zero overhead depending on your needs.

Comment: @rogerkasinsky we support accessing Bytes for byte[], portions of objects, direct anonymous memory, abd memory mapped files.